# app crashed while launching in phone but working fine in emulator (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.)

Tags: android, android-studio

Android app working fine in emulator.
But got crashed after installing the .apk file in phone

(Using android studio 2.2) phone using MI note

Disable the Instant Run option in Android Studio (tried already but not working)

error show below

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.
tools.fd.runtime.AppInfo
at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.<init>(BootstrapApplication.java:119)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4352)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: attach your Manifest

Answer (score 1):

Disable instant run from Android Studio. Do a clean and then run again.

To disable Instant Run Go to File --> Settings--> Build,Execution,Deployment -->Instant Run ---> uncheck "Enable instant run"

Comment: Thanks,solved the problem.  Have to restart the Android Studio after disabling instant run